# Is it possible to add class by hovering a submenu in Pinia and Nuxtjs?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, pinia

When a mouseover on a nav links, I want a class adds automatically by the Pinia in Nuxt.... For example, engineering item is hoverd in the nav then a submenu is shown ... when the mouseleves the engineeing item the submenu will be hidden

I tried to use conditional syntax inside the nav and writing action in the file store.ts which if for Pinia.

Header.vue

```
<template>
  <header class="header container-fluid mx-auto my-auto">
    <!-- Extra menu links -->
    <nav class="extra-nav bg-blue-500 w-full h-10 flex mx-auto"></nav>
    <!-- navbar -->
    <nav class="main-nav container mx-auto my-auto">
      <ul class="mx-auto my-auto headerUl flex">
        <!-- logo -->
        <li class="">
          <NuxtLink to="/" class="mx-auto my-auto">
            <img
              class="w-32 h-auto cursor-pointer my-auto mx-auto"
              src="@/img/peymantec-logo-en.jpg"
              alt="Peymantec Logo"
            />
          </NuxtLink>
        </li>
        <!-- MainMenu -->
        <li
          :key="`navItem-${i}`"
          v-for="(n, i) in mainMenu"
          class="mx-auto my-auto"
        >
          <NuxtLink
            :to="n.link"
            class="my-auto mx-auto w-1 py-3 headerLinks justify-between relative flex-row align-middle"
            @mouseover="n.active = !n.active"
          >
            {{ n.name }}
            <!-- mainSvg -->
            <div class="inline-flex mx-1 my-auto align-middle">
              <svg
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                width="10"
                height="10"
                viewBox="0 0 30 30"
              >
                <path
                  d="M27.963 6.75 30 8.787l-1.018 1.018-12.964 12.963L15 23.787 1.018 9.805 0 8.787 2.037 6.75l1.018 1.018L15 19.713 26.945 7.768l1.018-1.018z"
                ></path>
              </svg>
            </div>
          </NuxtLink>
          <!-- Triangels -->
          <!-- <NuxtLink
            class="my-auto mx-3 py-2 justify-center headerLinks_Triangel"
            :class="{ triangelActive: n.active }"
          >
          </NuxtLink> -->
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <!-- subMenus -->
    <!-- EngineeringsubMenus -->
    <nav
      class="container mx-auto my-auto w-full subMenu"
      :class="isHovered ? 'activeSubmenu' : ''"
      @mouseover="hoverSubs()"
    >
      <div class="flex flex-auto">
        <!-- ServicesSub  -->
        <ul class="servicesSub p-2">
          <li class="mb-3">خدمات</li>
          <li
            :key="`navItem-${i}`"
            v-for="(n, i) in servicesSub"
            class="w-full mx-auto my-auto inline-flex px-3 py-3"
          >
            <NuxtLink :to="n.link">{{ n.name }}</NuxtLink>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- ExpertiseSub -->
        <ul class="expertiseSub p-2">
          <li class="mb-3">تخصص</li>
          <li
            :key="`navItem-${i}`"
            v-for="(n, i) in expertiseSub"
            class="w-full mx-auto my-auto inline-flex px-3 py-3"
          >
            <NuxtLink :to="n.link">{{ n.name }}</NuxtLink>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- HowWeWorkSub -->
        <ul class="howWeWorkSub p-2">
          <li class="mb-3">ما چطور کار میکنیم؟</li>
          <li
            :key="`navItem-${i}`"
            v-for="(n, i) in howWeWorkSub"
            class="w-full mx-auto my-auto inline-flex px-3 py-3"
          >
            <NuxtLink :to="n.link">{{ n.name }}</NuxtLink>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
</template>

<script setup>
// Main Menu
const mainMenu = [
  {
    name: "مهندسی",
    link: "/engineering",
    active: false,
  },
  {
    name: "صنایع",
    link: "/services",
    active: false,
  },
  {
    name: "درباره",
    link: "/about",
    active: false,
  },
  {
    name: "تماس",
    link: "/contact",
    active: false,
  },
];

// Engineering SubMenu

const servicesSub = [
  {
    name: "توسعه نرم افزار",
    link: "/development",
  },
  {
    name: "پردازش ابری",
    link: "/cloud",
  },
  {
    name: "اینترنت اشیا‌ و هوش مصنوعی",
    link: "/iot",
  },
  {
    name: "کسب و کار هوشمند",
    link: "/smart",
  },
];

const expertiseSub = [
  {
    name: "توسعه وب، موبایل و بلاک چین",
    link: "/services",
  },
  {
    name: "توسعه واقعیت افزوده و ان اف تی",
    link: "/about",
  },
  {
    name: "طراحی تجربه و رابط کاربری",
    link: "/about",
  },
  {
    name: "علم داه و کلان داده",
    link: "/about",
  },
];

const howWeWorkSub = [
  {
    name: "کشف نیازهای پروژه",
    link: "/services",
  },
  {
    name: "طراحی خلاقانه و توسعه هوشمند",
    link: "/about",
  },
  {
    name: "بررسی کیفیت و عملکرد محصول",
    link: "/about",
  },
  {
    name: "اجرا و تحویل نهایی  پروژه",
    link: "/about",
  },
];
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.header {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flexbox;

  &Links {
    &_Triangel {
      border-bottom: 1rem solid transparent;
      border-left: 1rem solid transparent;
      border-right: 1rem solid transparent;
      width: 0.5rem;
    }
    &:hover {
      color: #b48648;
      fill: #b48648;
    }
  }
}
.triangelActive {
  border-bottom: 1rem solid #b48648 !important;
}
.subMenuActive {
  display: show !important;
}
</style>
```

store.ts

```
import { defineStore } from "pinia";
import { acceptHMRUpdate } from "pinia";
// import mainMenu from "components/Header.vue";

export const peymantecStore = defineStore({
  id: "peymantec-store",
  state: () => {
    return {
      isHovered: false,
      activeSubmenu: "subMenuActive",
    };
  },

  actions: {
    //  hoverSubs() => {
    // }
  },
  getters: {},
});

if (import.meta.hot) {
  import.meta.hot.accept(acceptHMRUpdate(peymantecStore, import.meta.hot));
}
```

`app.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <NuxtLayout>
      <NuxtPage />
    </NuxtLayout>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Not sure why you would want to use TS + Pinia for a hover effect (that can be done with regular vanilla CSS) but it's indeed feasible in your `hoverSubs` action.

Comment: Can you please complete the hoverSubs (). I am a bit confused because this is the first time I am using Typescript with Pinia and generally a Nuxt project. Thanks

Comment: No problem. I know SO is not a coding service but solving this issue could help others using Pinia with Nuxtjs3.